# Will changing Azure database tier clean the cache?

Tags: sql-server, azure

We are currently using a database in Azure and we will need to move the tier up to Business Critical but I was wondering if this will clear the SQL Server cache?

Currently we are using the cache to check how some stored procedures are performing and I'm afraid this change will cause our investigation to be reset.

Comment: Can you use Query Store for your investigations? This is persisted to disc rather than held in memory so will survive the database being spun up on a new replica - including changing tier. If you are moving up to Business Critical from some other tier then this will be different hardware so definitely anything in memory will be gone

Comment: @MartinSmith Thanks for the information, I was suspecting it would clear. The current scripts I'm using don't read the query store - I have another set that do read it, so maybe use those for this case.

Comment: @MartinSmith Can you set this as a reply so I can mark it as the correct answer please?

Comment: The reason I haven't given an answer is that I'm not sure without researching it which scale up operations (if any) will leave the instance running on the same replica and which won't. Business critical will be using hardware with locally attached SSD so I am confident that this will cause such a change without doing any research

Answer (score 1):

Actually changing the Azure SQL Database tier, won't directly wipe out the SQL Server cache. but, if the tier change involves a restart of the db, the cache will get cleared during that.

And about stored procedure performance investigations, let me share SQL code you can use to check the cache.

```
SELECT 
    objtype,
    usecounts,
    text
FROM 
    sys.dm_exec_cached_plans
CROSS APPLY 
    sys.dm_exec_sql_text(plan_handle)
WHERE 
    text LIKE 'YourStoredProcedure%'
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I just wanted to be sure that it does or does nor involve a retry.
As for the check cache for a stored procedure, thanks for the code, but I usually use [First Responder Kit](https://www.brentozar.com/first-aid/)  from Brent Ozar's site.